# How to use cached ticket with KerberosRestTemplate?

Tags: spring-security, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

I want to implement integration test for my spring security kerberos authentication. 
There is **KerberosRestTemplate** ([reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-kerberos/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#ssk-resttemplate)) for this purpose. **KerberosRestTemplate** has got a default constructor with description "Leave keyTabLocation and userPrincipal empty if you want to use cached ticket".

For research i wrote a trivial class:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        KerberosRestTemplate krt = new KerberosRestTemplate();
        String result = krt.getForObject("http://testserver.testad.local:8080/", String.class);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

When i run it, exception has thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error running rest call; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null name not allowed
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate.doExecute(KerberosRestT
emplate.java:196)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
        at edu.mezlogo.Application.main(Application.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null name not allowed
        at sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate.doExecute(KerberosRestT
emplate.java:182)
        ... 3 more
```

My **klist** contain correct cached ticket, for my service.

```
#2>     Client: deniz @ TESTAD.LOCAL
        Server: HTTP/testserver.testad.local @ TESTAD.LOCAL
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
        Ticket Flags 0x40a10000 -> forwardable renewable pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 2/5/2016 6:17:39 (local)
        End Time:   2/5/2016 16:16:32 (local)
        Renew Time: 2/12/2016 6:16:32 (local)
        Session Key Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
```

And my browser (firefox) has successful authenticated with kerberos sso.

I use Windows server 2012. And Windows 7 as client.

How to use cached ticket? (And does ktpass can generate client keytab?)

P.s. sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the Windows credentials cache - while Java is maintaining it's separate. In order to view the Java's credentials cache you should execute the `klist` command from your `JRE/bin` folder

Comment: And is there a way to make Java use Windows' `klist`?

Comment: @MichelJung you need to set AllowTGTSessionKey=1 property in registry. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6722928